# Cannot create table in MariaDB due to Constraint which doesnt exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb, innodb

I am trying to create the following table:

*invoice_government_levy_tracking*

With the following columns:

```
invoice_id - unsignedInteger (10)

government_levy_tracking_id - unsignedInteger (10)
```

However, whenever I attempt this I get the following error:

> #1005 - Can't create table 'database_invoice_government_levy_tracking' (errno: 150)

When I click the details there appears to be a *LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR* as follows:

> 180817  8:58:53 Error in foreign key constraint of table database/invoice_government_levy_tracking:
>   there is no index in the table which would contain the columns as the
>   first columns, or the data types in the table do not match the ones in
>   the referenced table or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared
>   NOT NULL. Constraint: ,   CONSTRAINT
>   "invoice_government_levy_tracking_invoice_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY
>   ("invoice_id") REFERENCES "invoices" ("id")

If I attempt to search for that constraint using:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_schema = 'database'
```

I can see all the constraints, and filtering the table there is no results for 
*invoice_government_levy_tracking_invoice_id_foreign* or if I filter just using *levy* or *invoice* its just the ones I expect and they don't relate to the table trying to be made.

This table has existed previously, but was deleted, and it doesn't show in the list of tables.

Any ideas on this one? It has me completely stumped.

-- EDIT --

Have attempted using the following SQL statement to create the table, and results in the same error:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_government_levy_tracking` (
    `invoice_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `government_levy_tracking_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE InnoDB
```

Additionally if I export the database, there is no reference to the attempted created table, nor the constraints

--- Additional Edit ---

So appears looking around further that somehow the database was corrupted, and innodb still has the table and the constraints in its records.

So solutions are, don't use that table name, or run a cleanup of innodb, or use another database so can use that table name.

Comment: Edit your question and show the SQL you are using to create the table.

Comment: Using PHPMyAdmin so its not even showing me the SQL to create it like it usually does

Comment: Apparently you are specifying a foreign key. Check your table definition/configuration to see if there is one. Searching after the error shouldn't show the constraint since it wasn't created because the create table failed.

Comment: Try writing a simple SQL statement to create the table. That way you can see if it works without the FK constraint.

Comment: Added the query used if just writing it out and running as SQL rather than using PHPMyAdmins creation tool

Comment: What's the `PRIMARY KEY` of `invoice_government_levy_tracking`?